# Sorting Dependency Automatically

Tags: java, maven, jar, apache-tika

I have an external library (say A.jar) which has loads and loads of stuff that I don't want, and a few that I want. The problem is, from my source Files (That I have written using that library, imports only a few of them), but surely including only those classes wont work( coz I tried). I don't know about internal dependency (if that's what it is called) of the class files inside (a very big) A.jar.

**Problem**
What tool I use to, say, import only those classes which are required (along with the dependencies That I don't know), into a different folder(or another Jar File).
Is Maven the right tool, and if so, how do I use it to achieving my goal?

The Library is the Apache-Tika Library. And I have Imported the following in my code.

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
```

I need to analyze doc, docx, pdf, odf, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, rtf, txt document. So, I need to know the minimal Library for this.

Comment: Is it really that important? The problem is that a class could be required due to reflection, making dependency detection difficult.

Comment: Are you already using Maven? Just going there for the dependency management is doable, but it's quite some work depending on your code base. Maven is not going to magically split JARs for you, though.

Comment: Also, if you tell what exactly libary "A" is, you'll probably get better/more specific answers.

Comment: Firstly, this is not a good idea. as @DaveNewton has commented. Secondly, Maven is not the tool to do this.

Comment: @Philipp Reichart : I've Updated the Question.

Comment: I've had a look at the dependencies of Tika and they look reasonable. If you need to actually *analyze* that many file formats, you won't be able to strip anything -- if you only need to *detect* these file formats, you could get away with the [tika-core as mentioned in the documentation](http://tika.apache.org/0.10/gettingstarted.html).

Comment: Do you want the general answer, or the specific Tika case? As for Tika you could either use Maven (Tika publishes poms which include the dependency info), or you could download the Tika OSGi bundle which includes all the dependencies in it

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://tika.apache.org/1.0/gettingstarted.html) you need tika-core-1.0.jar and tika-parsers-1.0.jar.  They total less than one meg.  What is dependency entry for Tika?